# Android WebView - innerHTML doesn't update value

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I use such function to load data to WebView after loading page. Console tells what value of innerHTML is update but on WebView change don't show. In browser console everything is fine.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


                function init_order() {


                    var elems = document.getElementById("body-id").getElementsByClassName("order_data");
                    if(arguments.length == elems.length){
                        console.log("Number of arguments is correct.");

                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Incorrect number of arguments.");
                        console.log("Class Tag: "+elems.length);
                        console.log("Arguments: "+arguments.length); 
                    }

                    for(i = 0; i < elems.length ; ++i){


                        var tag = elems[i];
                        var tagValue = elems[i].innerHTML;

                        if(tagValue.search("%@") != -1){


                            var replacedStr = tagValue.replace("%@",arguments[i]);

                            elems[i].innerHTML = replacedStr;
                            //console.log(arguments[i]);
                            console.log("value: "+elems[i].innerHTML);

                        }
                    }

                   // window.location.reload()
                }


                </script>
```

Comment: what is the element tag you trying to update?

Comment: These are series of elements which contains class order_data. In each of them i am looking for string "%@" and replace it with proper value from arguments table which I pass from Android:

e.g.  javascript:init_order("1410422483943","MONEY","kokoko","96427","0.70","0.0","0.1401400032043459","0.8401400032043458","XXXX1131","null","kokoko","kokoko")

Comment: the elements are input fields or p/span/div tags?

Comment: <p id="payment_type" class="order-nr order_data">Payment type: %@</p>
<p class="order-nr order_data">Customer: %@</p>

Comment: any console error that creeps in?

Comment: unfortuntelly no erros